# Emitting event from root component to router outlet child component

Tags: angular

I have the following structure:
app.component.html holds the following components:

```
<componentA>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I inject componentB into the router outlet and componentB has its own router outlet.

```
<componentB><router-outlet></router-outlet></componentB>
```

I inject componentC inside ComponentB´s router outlet

```
<componentC>
```

I want to send an event from ComponentA to ComponentC.

I am trying to use a service to accomplish this by injecting it into ComponentA which sends the event and ComponentC is subscribing to the event through the injected service. Component C is not receiving the events.

However if I move componentA inside ComponentB the event is successfully emitted to ComponentC.

How can I emit the event from ComponentA to ComponentC when ComponentA is located at the root in app.component.html?

**[UPDATE]**

I followed the example on [bidirectional service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) but the event is still not received. Here is the code:

My Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
   private mySource = new Subject<string>();
   source$ = this.mySource.asObservable();
   sendEvent(stringParam: string) {
      this.mySource.next(stringParam);
   }
}
```

Component A sends the event

```
 this.myService.sendEvent("test");
```

Component C subscribes and listens for the event

```
this.subscription = this.myService.source$.subscribe(stringParam => {
  console.log('Received event: ' + stringParam);
});
```

I am using Angular RC5. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Try with `private mySource = new BehaviorSubject<string>();`. The sending component might send before the receiving subscribed.

Comment: Without luck :( thanks for your help. I am going to change my project structure a bit, eliminating the child router outlet in component B which may solve my issue.

Comment: Hard to tell without more details. Did you provide the service at both components? It must be only provided at the ancestor (or root) otherwise both component get different instances.

Comment: This was the case :) the service was provided in the app.module and inside one of my components. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first, the router doesn't add components **into** the `<router-outlet>` but makes it a **sibling**. This is because of how `ViewContainerRef.createComponent` works.

Events sent from `EventEmitter` also don't bubble and therefore can only be used to add event handlers on child elements using `(event)="doSomething()"`.

A shared service is usually the right thing to use in your situation.
For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: I was having a similar issue and resolved it with shared service. Thanks.

Comment: What if the child component is used in several places and needs to behave differently in each place. Should I put some kind of interface on the parent service that the child uses? Or inject several shared services to handle subsets of behavior.

Comment: Difficult to tell with this little information. You could wrap your component with different components and also provide different implemenatations of  the service in the wrapper component to be injected to the child.